UPDATE column with Y or N if data exists in another table
I have a MySQL 5.7 table with 8 million distinct email records.
I have another table with about 2 million records with emails that are not distinct.
I want to see the emails from the larger table that exist in the smaller table.
I added a column in my larger table and called it in_2nd_table and left it blank.
I then wrote a query that looks like this:
UPDATE `mainTable` set `in_2nd_table` = 
  CASE WHEN `email` IN (SELECT `email` FROM `2ndTable`) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END;

But I'm guessing the tables are so large that the query keeps conking out.  I keep getting a 500 that looks similar to this: https://i.sstatic.net/0bn2R.png
I also tried to create a table like this:
CREATE TABLE `test` AS SELECT * FROM `mainTable` WHERE `email` NOT IN (SELECT `email` FROM `2ndTable`);

But that kept conking out as well, throwing the same 500 error.
There are no INDEXES on the tables.  I tried to add an INDEX on the larger table, but again, I got the 500 error.
I just want to be able to see what records from the larger table exist in the smaller table.
How can I make this work?

500 is a PHP error, remember phpMyAdmin is a PHP App. Run the code from a mysql terminal therefore removing all the PHP limits

@RiggsFolly - So I have access to a mysql terminal.  At the top of the terminal, it reads, "This interface provides command line access to the server's 'root' account".  Are you saying I can run queries from this terminal?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-getting-started/en/

I would write your logic as an update join:
UPDATE mainTable t1
LEFT JOIN `2ndTable` t2
    ON t2.email = t1.email
SET t1.in_2nd_table = CASE WHEN t2.email IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END;

The above query would benefit from the following index on the second table:
CREATE INDEX idx ON `2ndTable` (email);

This index would allow ths rapid lookup of each email value from the first table against the second table.

Testing from the terminal... albeit, I didn't add the Index yet.  Right now, it appears the terminal is just sitting there.  I'm assuming it's running the query.

So I opened another terminal to check if the query is still running.  Under Time it reads '1002', and under State, it reads 'Sending data'.  Guess I'll just keep waiting.

I had to stop the query, as it was taking too long.  I added the indexes to both tables and ran the same UPDATE query, and it took 4 minutes to complete.  Thank you.  Your suggestion worked.
